# convert normal query to subquery comes out with different results

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I'm doing a question using subquery(without JOIN) and normal (using JOIN) query, but at the end, the results are different from this two query, I can't figure out this problem.

The question is about list the dog owner details which has booked at least twice in this platform

```
PET_OWNER(Owner_id,Oname,OAdd),
PET(Pet_id,Pname,PType),
BOOKING(Booking_num,Pet_id)
```

each owner may have >=1 dogs,
each dog may have >=1 booking

```
SELECT PET_OWNER.Owner_id,Oname,OAdd,COUNT(*) AS BOOKING
FROM PET_OWNER,
     PET,
     BOOKING 
WHERE PET_OWNER.Owner_id = PET.Owner_id
  AND PET.Pet_id = BOOKING.Pet_id
  AND PType = 'DOG'
GROUP BY PET_OWNER.Owner_id, Oname, OAdd
HAVING COUNT(*) >=2
ORDER BY PET_OWNER.Owner_id;`
```

this is the normal query,showing which dog owner has booked at least twice

---

```
SELECT *
FROM PET_OWNER
WHERE Owner_id IN ( SELECT Owner_id FROM PET
                    WHERE Pet_id IN ( SELECT Pet_id FROM BOOKING)
                      AND PType = 'DOG'
                    GROUP BY Owner_id 
                    HAVING COUNT(*) >1);
```

the problem in this subquery is, the result is showing which owner has at least two dogs but not which dog owner has made booking at least twice.
the subquery has automatically show me the distinct pet_id,
so that i cant count on the Pet_id in table Booking because it always shown only 1
**any join is not allowed in this subquery

what changes should i make in the subquery code?
i expect this two query have the same results

Comment: why you use subquery instead  of join ??? .. the wheri IN work as a select distinct the JOIN work a select not distinct

Comment: Sample data would really be helpful here.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: mysql or oracle? Since you're not getting an error for incorrect group by, I assume mysql. Please don't tag products not involved.

Comment: Tip of today: Use the modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `group by` in sub query as following:

```
SELECT * FROM 
PET_OWNER 
WHERE Owner_id IN 
  ( SELECT Owner_id FROM PET
     WHERE Pet_id IN ( SELECT Pet_id FROM BOOKING 
     GROUP BY PET_ID HAVING COUNT(1) >1 ) AND PType = 'DOG';
```

Cheers!!

Comment: OMG YOU ARE SO PRO MAN!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to do 2 subqueries for this purpose:

```sql
SELECT * FROM PET_OWNER
 WHERE OWNER_Id IN (SELECT Owner_id FROM PET 
                     WHERE PType = 'DOG'
                       AND Pet_Id IN (SELECT Pet_id 
                                        FROM BOOKING
                                       GROUP BY Pet_id
                                       HAVING COUNT(*) > 1))
    OR OWNER_Id IN (SELECT Owner_id FROM PET 
                     WHERE PType = 'DOG'
                       AND Pet_Id IN (SELECT Pet_id 
                                        FROM BOOKING)
                     GROUP BY Pet_id
                     HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the dog owners that have booked at least twice with a `join` and `group by`:

```
select p.owner_id
from booking b join
     pet p
     on p.pet_id = b.pet_id
where p.type = 'Dog'
group by p.owner_id
having count(*) >= 2;
```

You can get the details in many ways.  A simple approach uses `in`:

```
select o.*
from owner o
where o.owner_id in (select p.owner_id
                     from booking b join
                          pet p
                          on p.pet_id = b.pet_id
                     where p.type = 'Dog'
                     group by p.owner_id
                     having count(*) >= 2
                    );
```